# Specific files for using Google Drive Service (on SDK)

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Good day, I am currently a noob in Google Drive SDK and I am planning to integrate it in my webapp. I checked out google-api-php-client from their svn and I noticed it's a bit large to include it all in my project (it's 5.6 mb). Excluding all but the **src** folder, it's still large for me (3.9 mb). I want to include **only** the files needed for the Google Drive integration to work. But I do not know what files do these two (Google_Client.php and Google_DriveService.php as in Google Developers' sample) depend on.

Can you guys pinpoint what files (that are not related to Drive) I can safely delete? I really want the total file size to be as small as possible 'cause I believe that it can affect the project's loading time.

Thanks(and pardon my English)! :)

Answer (score 2):

Only checkout the library source code and remove all services other than Drive and Oauth2:

```
svn checkout http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src
```

Remove all files under `src/contrib` but preserve the following:

- src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php
- src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php